# Trouble running code on a network or onedrive folder

Tags: excel, vba, network-drive

I found some code that has been tremendously helpfull.  Problem is that this does not work if the folder directory is on a mapped drive or onedrive.  I have looked at various other exmaples to change this, but I am stuck.  This piece of code loops through all the excel sheets in a folder, copies and paste's the content and then and then saves them somwhere else.

In short I simply need this code to also function on onedrive or a mapped network drive.

The code that does this

```
Sub Work_all_excelsheets() ' Run Age Report Button
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook, WS1 As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim wbname As String, killname As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim myCSVPath As String, myCSVPath2 As String, myCSVPath3 As String, myCSVFileName As String, currpath As String

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Call Declare_Sheets

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Call Unlock_allsheets

Success2 = True
RProw = WSSS.Range("M7")
ERRrow = WSSS.Range("M6")
'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Age to Process\"
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsx*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)
    
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
    
    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
    Set WS1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    WS1.Range("A1:I1000").Copy
    WSAS.Range("K11:S1010").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Call Run_Action_Sheet_Service

    'Save and Close Workbook
    If Success Then
        wbname = wb.name
        currpath = wb.path
        myCSVPath = WBMAST.path & "\FINISHED"
        myCSVPath2 = myCSVPath & "\" & Year(Date)
        myCSVPath3 = myCSVPath2 & "\" & Month(Date)
        myCSVFileName = myCSVPath3 & "\" & wbname
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'On Error GoTo err
        If Not fso.FolderExists(myCSVPath2) Then
            fso.CreateFolder myCSVPath2
        End If
        If Not fso.FolderExists(myCSVPath3) Then
            fso.CreateFolder myCSVPath3
        End If
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Call Protect_allsheets(wb)
        With wb
        .SaveAs filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=61, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
        End With
        killname = currpath & "\" & wbname
        Kill killname
        
    Else
        wb.Close Savechanges:=False
    End If
      
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

err:

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

' Add names and email adresses to Outstanding units

Call Add_Customer_Details

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

If Success2 = False Then
    MsgBox ("There were errors with some of the Files. Please check the Err Report and the Age to Process folder.")
    WSError.Activate
Else
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"
End If

Call Create_Protection

'Unlock the columns for the report
Dim Exists5 As Boolean

'First check if the sheet exists
For I = 1 To WBMAST.Worksheets.Count
    If WBMAST.Worksheets(I).name = WSReport.name Then Exists5 = True
Next I
If Exists5 Then
    WSReport.Unprotect Password:="XXXXXX"
    With WSReport
        .Activate
        .Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Allow_ChangesWS1", Range:=.Range("O3:P5000")
        .Protect Password:="XXXXXX"
    End With
End If
    


End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like it would work on a mapped drive, but not on SharePoint/OneDrive.

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesnt :/

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  What happens when you run the code?  Which part(s) fail?